# How do I print another list of elements while keeping my last input?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to print more than 1 list of elements in an array. I just want to repeat the process of what I made while keeping the last input I just printed until I'm satisfied on how many lists there is. (I'm a newbie)

```
list1 = []
n1 = int(input("Number of items: "))

for i in range(0, n1):
    elements = (input())

    list.append(elements)


def Given(list1):
    return list1

print(Given(list1))
```

Comment: Have a function do your inputs and return a list.  Now, you can call that function in a loop and collect those lists in another list.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Try using json or dictionaries. that way u can add lists to the dictionary and you can print the required list with the index.

Comment: also a typo from your side..! `list.append(elements)` -> `list1.append(elements)`

Comment: share the desired output also by taking any testcase..